# how to use clob compare in where clause. ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am trying select a row using a clob column in the where clause. i have tried to use `dbms_lob.compare` but does not work. Below is my query. the clob column is `arg2`

```
SELECT id 
FROM CCP.worker_jobs 
WHERE  (  id = :id ) 
AND  (  job = :job ) 
AND  (  args = :args ) 
AND  (  arg1 = :arg1 ) 
AND  (  flag = :flag ) 
AND  (  pid = :pid ) 
AND  (  token = :token ) 
AND  ( dbms_lob.instr(arg2, :arg2) > 0 )
;
```

but it does not work it keeps complaining.

```
CREATE TABLE WORKER_JOBS 
(
  ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, JOB VARCHAR2(64 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ARGS NUMBER(1, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, ARG1 VARCHAR2(64 BYTE) 
, ARG3 VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) 
, SERVER VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) 
, ATTEMPTS NUMBER(5, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL 
, FLAG VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'Q' NOT NULL 
, TS_CREATED TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
, TS_UPDATED TIMESTAMP(6) 
, UPDATED_BY VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) 
, CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT 'unknown' NOT NULL 
, OUTPUT VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) 
, PID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) 
, TOKEN VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, ARG2 CLOB 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE CCP 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 131072 
  NEXT 131072 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NO INMEMORY 
NOPARALLEL 
LOB (ARG2) STORE AS SYS_LOB0000057683C00018$$ 
( 
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW 
  CHUNK 8192 
  NOCACHE 
  LOGGING 
  TABLESPACE CCP 
  STORAGE 
  ( 
    INITIAL 131072 
    NEXT 131072 
    MINEXTENTS 1 
    MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
    PCTINCREASE 0 
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
  )  
);

CREATE INDEX WORKER_JOBS_CREATED ON WORKER_JOBS (TS_CREATED ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE CCP 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 131072 
  NEXT 131072 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;

CREATE INDEX WORKER_JOBS_FLAG ON WORKER_JOBS (FLAG ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE CCP 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 131072 
  NEXT 131072 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;

CREATE INDEX WORKER_JOBS_JOB ON WORKER_JOBS (JOB ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE CCP 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 131072 
  NEXT 131072 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX WORKER_JOBS_PK ON WORKER_JOBS (ID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE CCP 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 131072 
  NEXT 131072 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;

ALTER TABLE WORKER_JOBS
ADD CONSTRAINT WORKER_JOBS_PK PRIMARY KEY 
(
  ID 
)
USING INDEX CCP.WORKER_JOBS_PK
ENABLE;
```

data i am using

```
(
    [:id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 249
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
        )

    [:job] => Array
        (
            [0] => reAnalyze
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 1
        )

    [:args] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [:arg1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 118593
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 1
        )

    [:flag] => Array
        (
            [0] => P
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [:pid] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

    [:token] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
    [:arg2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ["18637512","18637514","18637517","18637518","18637520","18637522","18637524","18637526","18637676","18637677","18637678","18637861","18637862","18637863","18637864","18637865","18637866","18637867","18637047","18637044","18637045","18637046","18637048","18637049","18637050","18637051","18637052","18637053","18637054","18637068","18637882","18637883","18637884","18637885","18637886","18637887","18637888","18637889","18637066","18637067","18637157","18637158","18637159","18637160","18637161","18637162","18637163","18637528","18637530","18637532","18637534","18637536","18637538","18637540","18637542","18637544","18637546","18637548","18637685","18637686","18637687","18637688","18637689","18637690","18637691","18637692","18637693","18637694","18637695","18637868","18637869","18637872","18637873","18637874","18637875","18637876","18637877","18637878","18637058","18637055","18637870","18637871","18637056","18637057","18637059","18637060","18637061","18637062","18637063","18637064","18637065","18637164","18637165","18637166","18637167","18637550","18637552","18637168","18637169","18637170","18637171","18637172","18637173","18637174","18637554","18637556","18637558","18637560","18637562","18637564","18637566","18637568","18637570","18637696","18637697","18637698","18637699","18637700","18637701","18637702","18637703","18637704","18637705","18637706","18637879","18637880","18637881","18637679","18637680","18637681","18637682","18637683","18637684","18637674","18637675","18637857","18637858","18637859","18637860","18637847","18637848","18637849","18637850","18637851","18637852","18637853","18637854","18637855","18637856","18637508","18637510","18637571","18637573","18637707","18637708","18637709","18637710","18637711","18637712","18637713","18637714","18637715","18637717","18637075","18637076","18637077","18637078","18637079","18637080","18637186","18637187","18637188","18637189","18637190","18637191","18637192","18637193","18637194","18637195","18637216","18637593","18637595","18637597","18637599","18637782","18637783","18637784","18637785","18637786","18637787","18637788","18637106","18637103","18637104","18637105","18637600","18637601","18637602","18637603","18637604","18637605","18637606","18637726","18637721","18637723","18637724","18637728","18637730","18637732","18637734","18637736","18637738","18637740","18637084","18637081","18637082","18637083","18637220","18637085","18637086","18637087","18637088","18637089","18637090","18637091","18637217","18637218","18637219","18637221","18637222","18637223","18637224","18637225","18637226","18637227","18637607","18637608","18637609","18637610","18637611","18637612","18637613","18637614","18637615","18637616","18637617","18637748","18637742","18637744","18637746","18637750","18637751","18637753","18637754","18637755","18637776","18637777","18637095","18637092","18637093","18637094","18637096","18637097","18637098","18637099","18637100","18637101","18637102","18637229","18637231","18637233","18637235","18637257","18637259","18637261","18637263","18637265","18637267","18637269","18637778","18637779","18637780","18637781","18637719","18637890","18637073","18637070","18637071","18637072","18637074","18637069","18637175","18637176","18637177","18637178","18637179","18637180","18637181","18637182","18637183","18637184","18637185","18637575","18637577","18637579","18637581","18637583","18637585","18637587","18637589","18637591","18637622","18637623","18637624","18637625","18637626","18637627","18637628","18637789","18637790","18637791","18637792","18637121","18637122","18637123","18637124","18637125","18637313","18637314","18637316","18637318","18637320","18637322","18637324","18637326","18637328","18637330","18637332","18637632","18637629","18637630","18637843","18637844","18637845","18637846","18637418","18637420","18637422","18637424","18637426","18637428","18637430","18637631","18637633","18637634","18637635","18637636","18637637","18637638","18637639","18637820","18637821","18637822","18637823","18637824","18637825","18637826","18637827","18637828","18637829","18637126","18637127","18637128","18637129","18637130","18637131","18637132","18637133","18637134","18637135","18637136","18637137","18637334","18637356","18637358","18637360","18637362","18637364","18637366","18637368","18637370","18637372","18637374","18637640","18637641","18637642","18637643","18637644","18637645","18637646","18637647","18637648","18637649","18637650","18637830","18637831","18637832","18637833","18637834","18637835","18637380","18637382","18637384","18637386","18637388","18637390","18637392","18637394","18637416","18637376","18637378","18637651","18637652","18637653","18637654","18637655","18637656","18637657","18637658","18637659","18637660","18637661","18637836","18637837","18637838","18637839","18637840","18637841","18637842","18637793","18637794","18637795","18637816","18637817","18637818","18637819","18637114","18637107","18637108","18637109","18637110","18637111","18637112","18637113","18637271","18637273","18637275","18637297","18637299","18637301","18637303","18637305","18637307","18637309","18637311","18637618","18637619","18637620","18637621","18637138","18637461","18637463","18637465","18637467","18637469","18637471","18637473","18637475","18637673","18637497","18637499","18637501","18637503","18637505","18637507","18637668","18637669","18637670","18637671","18637672","18637432","18637434","18637436","18637438","18637662","18637663","18637664","18637665","18637666","18637667","18637440","18637442","18637444","18637446","18637448","18637450","18637452","18637453","18637456","18637457","18637459"]
            [1] => 5622
            [2] => 1
        )
```

error i get is `ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `:arg2` varchar2 parameter having **length > 4000** in parameter of the SQL. SQL supports only 4000 characters varchar2.

You must reduce the length of the variable.

Cheers!!

Comment: i have tried `( dbms_lob.instr(arg2, to_clob(:arg2)) > 0 )` i still get same error

Comment: Updated my answer. It is caused due to `:arg2`'s length which is in SQL and SQL supports only 4000 characters in `Varchar2`